# How to change font color of notes made on Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

[image]

Its possible to add notes in a pdf file with macOS Preview app, by doing:

```
Tools > Annotate > Note
```

Or usinng shortcut `ctrl+cmd+N`.

The note is enclosed by a colored box and its possible to change its (background) color by right-click on it.

While editing/composing note text color is black.

But (the issue is) notes showing on left panel by:

```
View > Highlights and Notes
```

Or using shortcut `opt+cmd+4`.

They appear with white font color and its almost impossible to read them, because color contrast between font and background is not good.

Main question: How can I change font color?

Additional question: Can I make font color the same on the left panel as it is on the note which appear on a page in the pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

For me, this problem happened when I switched to "dark mode" from my system preferences. when I switched back to light mode, I could read the notes again. I didn't find another way around this :(

Answer (score 0):

Preview Version 10.1 (944.6.16.1) - the version I'm using.

The note background can be changed and that change is reflected in the sidebar. When dark enough the white letters are visible.

- create the new note ( ⌃ ⌘ N )
- R-click on the note and select a color from the popup abbreviated color pallet
- OR  focus on the note and select the color pallet on the toolbar

The above will not default subsequent notes to the selected color.

---

**Linked Note**

[This SO thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351501/19602) says:  *I can only change the colour when the note is not linked to a highlighted text section*

*HOWEVER*

Creating a linked note on existing highlighted text ( R-click-popup-menu )  - **the note background takes on the highlight color**